# open and close DrawerLayout null exception

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am trying to add DrawerLayout on my app but the items are not responding to click. I have tried logging the output on the console but nothing show up when the items are clicked. Here is my code

MainActivity

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Toolbar toolbar;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawal);
 drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawal_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);


    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer,R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
   @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.i("info", String.valueOf(id));
    switch (id){

        case R.id.dashoard:
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "This is dasbhard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.hire_mechanic_id:
            Intent intents = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, LIkelyProblemsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intents);
            break;

        case R.id.tow_van_id:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hire a Toyin Van", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

    }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
    return true;
}

}
```

DrawerLayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawal_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_dashboard" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_navigation_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<item android:title="Dashboard">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="item 1"
            android:icon="@drawable/mechanic"
            android:id="@+id/dashoard"/>
        <item
            android:title="item 2"
            android:icon="@drawable/mechanic"
            android:id="@+id/hire_mechanic_id"/>

        <item
            android:title="item 3"
            android:icon="@drawable/spareparts"
            android:id="@+id/spare_parts_id"/>

        <item

            android:title="item 4"
            android:id="@+id/tow_van_id"
            android:icon="@drawable/toyin_van" />
    </menu>
   </item>
</menu>
```

I have checked the drawerlayout, menu and the main activity but I can't really figure out what the problem is. Anyone one who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to call `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener` listener that's why navigation item not being called, just add this line

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Hope it will help you!!